# Merging and resizing an image

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I'm attempting to expand my function from simply resizing an image, to also adding a watermark.  The problem is the watermark is not being added.  I've confirmed the path is correct.  Why is it not working?

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->getFile());

    $size = getimagesize($this->getFile());  

    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('../watermark.png');
    $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
    $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

    $dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 10;  

    $dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5; 

    //die($watermark_width);

    $thumb_image = imagecreatetruecolor($this->getThumbWidth(), $this->getThumbHeight());

    imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);  

    imagecopyresampled( $thumb_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->getThumbResizeWidth(), $this->getThumbResizeHeight(), $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight() );
    imagejpeg( $thumb_image, $this->getThumbDestination(), $this->getThumbQuality() );

    imagedestroy($thumb_image);
    imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: What are `$dest_x` and `$dest_y`? Are you sure they fall within the bounds of the destination image?

Comment: Oops.  Forgot to copy over some code form the other script.  I think it's x and y placement of the watermark?

Comment: I know what they're used for; what I mean is what is their actual value when you run the code?

Comment: They're both returning -5.  Why aren't the other variables returning anything?  The images are definitely different sizes.

Comment: Hmm... what are the runtime values of `$size[0]`, `$size[1]`, `$watermark_width` and `$watermark_height`? Can you add them as comments in the code?

Comment: Actually I got it working, but It's brought up another question, so perhaps I should open a new question, but I'll ask here first.  The transparent PNG is showing as a white box.  Why is that?

Comment: I would take a look at [this comment](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787) in the `imagecopymerge()` docs. It probably has to do with the alpha channel.

Comment: Also, it's considered good SO etiquette when you figure out the answer to your own question to post it as an answer yourself, so that future visitors might get some help from it.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the code I found a couple of errors, the major one being, contrary to my belief, an incorrect file path for the watermark.png.  The is updated and does work for me.  There is still an issue with alpha transparency, however.